# Processing of Getting Maximum value from Mongo using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am writing a basic app where in I need to get the maximum value from Mongo DB through c#.
I figured that

```
collection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("_id")).SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

However I wanted to understand the processing part. 
Does the FindAll() first brings all the values from Mongo and then processes it in C# for the maximum value or it does the processing at Mongo DB level before bringing it to C#.

I've been unable to find any proper answer to this query, any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `FindAll` and check if you get the similar result ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad No it doesn't work if I remove the FindAll, as SetSortOrder is a method inside FindAll()

Comment: What is the class which was instantiated into the collection variable?

Comment: Sort, limit is performed on MongoDB server before returning result set to client.